# initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter) in java maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, annotations

I am getting started with java maven project and I am new to this. I have used spring annotations and when I run my test class it gives following error.

> FirstTryTest.testFirst
>   initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)
>   java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching
>   [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=testFirst],
>   {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=testFirst(com.mycompany.test.FirstTryTest)],
>   {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=com.mycompany.test.FirstTryTest,fLeadingIdentifier=testFirst]]
>   from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@7b0070  at
>   org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:77)  at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

My test class look like this.

```
    package com.mycompany.test;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;

import com.mycompany.config.AppConfig;
import com.mycompany.service.FirstTryService;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class FirstTryTest {

    @Autowired
    private FirstTryService firstTryService;

    @Test
    public void testFirst() {

        Integer rCal = firstTryService.cal(10, 10);
        Assert.assertNotNull(rCal);
        // System.out.println(rCal);

    }

    @Test
    public void testSecond() {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }

}
```

following is my service and service impl file.

```
package com.mycompany.service;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
public interface FirstTryService {

    Integer cal(Integer x, Integer y);

}

package com.mycompany.serviceImpl;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.mycompany.service.FirstTryService;

@Service
public class FirstTryServiceImpl implements FirstTryService {

    @Override
    public Integer cal(Integer x, Integer y) {
        Integer calPlus = x + y;

        return calPlus;
    }

}
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same error as you posted.Then I found this error caused by the unnecessary input parameter in the testing function. I can not tell you have the same cause. But you can use my steps to get the details of the error(seems that is a bug for eclipse, at least it should enhance on this subject).

In eclipse, don't select the testing function alone to test, while select "Run all the tests in the selected project" option on the Test Tab, when select the Junit project name after click on Run->"Run(Debug) Configuration".

You can reference to my answer:
[JUnit testing got initializationError with java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710837/junit-testing-got-initializationerror-with-java-lang-exception-no-tests-found-m/47749561)