# java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching JUNIT 4 with SpringBoot

Tags: maven, spring-boot, junit4

I am using junit 4 to create tests for controller. Below is the TestController test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(EmployeeController.class)

public class TestEmployeeController {

     @Autowired
     private MockMvc mvc;

     @MockBean
     private EmployeeService service;

     @BeforeClass
        public static void beforeTest() {
            System.out.println("Starting test engine");
        }

        @AfterClass
        public static void AfterTest() {
            System.out.println("Terminating test engine");
        }


     @Test
     public void testfindEmployeeById()  {
         System.out.println("here");
         Employee emp = new Employee();
         emp.setId(1);
         given(service.findById(emp.getId())).willReturn(emp);

         try {
            mvc.perform( MockMvcRequestBuilders
                      .get("/employee/findById/{id}", emp.getId())
                      .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                      .andReturn();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

The issue ocurrs when i try to run the test from eclipse, i get the below error. i also renamed the method with a prefix test but still its not working.

I guess the issue might be because of webmvc annotation but not sure. 
In Eclipse console logger provides the below info.

**DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.SpringHiber.testController.TestEmployeeController]**

I also tried annotating @Profile in controller and @ActiveProfiles in testController method. But it didn't help.

Detail Info about the exception i am getting is below.

```
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=testfindEmployeeById], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=testfindEmployeeById(com.SpringHiber.testController.TestEmployeeController)], {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=com.SpringHiber.testController.TestEmployeeController,fLeadingIdentifier=testfindEmployeeById]] from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@2aceadd4
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Below i am posting the rest controller class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")

public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired EmployeeService eService;

@GetMapping(path= {"/findById/{id}"},produces= {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public Employee findById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return eService.findById(id);   
    }
}
```

Please let me know what am i missing in the above code?

Comment: I was able to run your tests in Intellij without any change. Here is a link to similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710837/junit-testing-got-initializationerror-with-java-lang-exception-no-tests-found-m

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The linked helped me a lot. @ContextConfiguration was missing.